# Why is the drawable overlapping the text in my tabview

Tags: android, tabwidget

Why does the tab text overlap the drawable in the tab? Is there a way to prevent this? Is the drawable always centered? What's the point of being able to add text as well as a drawable to the indicator if it gives this output.

[image]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <LinearLayout        
        android:orientation="vertical"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:padding="5dp">  
        <TabWidget            
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>        
        <FrameLayout            
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
            android:padding="5dp" />  
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**java**

```
 host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("_tab2") 
                .setIndicator("Authors",res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode))  
                .setContent(new Intent(this, AuthorList.class)));
```

Can anyone else help? I've tried everythin I can think of and it looks like this both in my phone and my emulator. I've used tabs before and it didn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the "Size and positioning" section in: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html

Most likely you have icons with dimensions that are under the incorrect resolution level (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi). This happened to me when my icons were 30x30 under ldpi. I resized them to 28x28 and put them under mdpi as the documentation suggests.

In addition, the documentation recommends against using colors, especially for unselected tabs as you have done. Making them grayscale and using the gray/white paradigm makes it look a lot cleaner with that theme.

Comment: What I posted was obviously not production value... I just used the default drawables. The point is it wasn't correctly positioning the icons and the text. Using smaller drawables would have helped, but it doesn't solve the problem, it just makes the drawable small enough that it doesn't overlap the text. Anyway, this question is 7 months old now and the project long complete. I never found a satisfactory solution except that it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

in each instance that I've used this, Its worked for me, but for you the only thing I see that may help, is try upping the padding just a tiny bit, check out if it works better with more padding to the word

Comment: Add padding to which exactly?

Comment: What are you using the frame layout for?

Comment: That's how a tabhost layout has to be defined. The framelayout is where android puts the contents of the tab