# Local icons in Android Options Menu stretch to fill menu item, obscure Title

Tags: android

***I'm new, so links and images are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/nolanramy/)***

Hi,

I'm likely making a silly mistake... hoping to find out what that is.

I'd like to use a few of the standard menu icons (ic_menu_refresh, etc.) in my app's Options Menu. And I'd like to set the icons in the xml file for the menu. I read in a few places that I can use the following:

```
<item android:id="@+id/quit"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
      android:title="Quit" />
```

to make a quit button in my menu. And this works nicely. However, I'd also like to use some other icons, like ic_menu_stop.png, which are apparently "not public" **[link1]**. Also, I've read in a few places that it's not a great idea to "reference internal graphics like that" **[link2]**. Likewise, I don't want to use the asterisk workaround **[link3]** to allow access to private resources. The solution offered is to make a local copy of the drawables.

So I copied the image files I wanted from `C:\...\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi` into my project's `res\drawable` folder, and then changed the above xml to:

```
<item android:id="@+id/quit"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
      android:title="Quit" />
```

However, this causes the icon to stretch (I believe the icon is stretched - and not simply a bigger (hdpi) image file - because it's slightly blurred) and either obscure or crowd out the title text, so all I see is the oversized, blurry icon. Of course, I also tried copying the icon from the `drawable-mdpi` folder: using the mdpi icon doesn't obscure the title, but the icon is slighlty undersized and blurry.

I wanted a screenshot, so I switched to running the app on my emulator. However, the blurring isn't apparent, and the local mdpi image seems to match the internal one I'm referencing:

**[screenshot]** (follow the link at the top!)

I have double-checked :), and it really is blurred on my phone (Motorola Droid).

It also occurred to me that the referenced one might be getting the icon via an xml file (like a state-list drawable), and that the xml file somehow defined how the image was to be drawn. I tried making one with a bitmap element, and tried setting a couple of the properties in ways I thought might help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
 android:gravity="top"
 android:filter="false" />
```

It worked to display the icon (I was proud of myself), but didn't affect the stretching issue.

I also found these **[link4 and link5]** pages, but they seemed to have different issues.

Perhaps I should be copying the icons from another location? Am I on the right track with the xml file? Help?

Thanks,

Nolan

Comment: I was having the EXACT same problem. I haven't found a solution yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982461/why-is-the-drawable-overlapping-the-text-in-my-tabview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the icon appear correctly in all screen densities, then you should create your own drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc folders and copy the icons into each of those.

That way the correct size icon will be used for each density.  For more details on how this works, see [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), particularly the section on resource qualifiers.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. The drawable should stretch to fit